How can i find the average of the product of two functions in polar coordinates?
I have 2 equations in polar coordinates that are only dependent on $\theta$ and not r:
$$
f=F(\theta)\\
g=g(\theta)
$$
How can I find the product of $<f.g>$. That is the product of the 2 functions, averaged over all $\theta$?

If the function does not depend on $r$ average it over $\theta$ only.
